# Setting the default web application for virtual hosts on Weblogic 12c

Tags: oracle, weblogic12c

I have read in the Oracle documentation that is possible to set the default web application for a Virtual Host, but I can't find where exactly in web logic to do this.

The docs I'm referencing can be found here under 'Virtual Hosting and the Default Web Application': https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24329_01/web.1211/e24432/web_server.htm#CNFGD200

The scenario is as follows:

- I have 2 web applications deployed on a Web Logic server one under the context '/authoring' and one under the context '/publish'
- I also have 2 Virtual Hosts configured. One with the domain 'authoring.com' and one with the domain 'publish.com'
- I have targeted the '/authoring' app to the virtual host 'authoring.com' and the '/publish' to 'publish.com'.
- I can access both apps through these domains if I type the context names e.g. authoring.com/authoring and publish.com/publish

What I need to do:

- Set the default web app for the virtual host so that the domain serves up the default application on the domain root (as mentioned in the linked docs) e.g. 'authoring.com/' will serve up '/authoring' but the URL will remain 'authoring.com/'.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I've managed to find a reasonable workaround. Despite what the docs say there is no clear way to set up an app deployed to a non-root context (e.g. "/publish" or "/author"), on a virtual host, as the 'default web app'.

However, you can deploy each app explicitly to the root context of it's virtual host and make it the default app that way.

The obvious downside to this is that you can't test the apps using the IP address, you need to test the apps via the domain name of the virtual host.

You can work around this if you don't own the domains by mapping the IP addresses to the virtual host domains in the 'hosts' file of your machine. Not a great solution if you need to give access to the apps to non-technical people e.g. for testing and quality assurance, but fine for development.

Comment: One of your answers [is being discussed on Meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/367677/how-to-react-to-user-reacting-with-i-dont-care-to-comments-explaining-him-to). You are welcome to post a comment or an answer there.